# reinstating index on Mongoose after deleting collection

Tags: mongoose

I'm using Mongoose ORM in a NodeJS application. Working on integration testing, I wrote a function that deletes all collections `afterEach` test.

But now there's an issue where the unique constraint index is not reinstated after the collection is deleted.

This test works when it's run in isolation because the collection is not deleted before the test run.

```
it('should fail to save when identifier exists', function(done){
  newItem.identifier = existingItem.identifier;
  newItem.save(function (err, result) {
    should.exist(err);
    done(null);
  });
});
```

But when it's running within the overall test suite, between each test the collections are dropped using this helper method:

```
function deleteCollection(collection, done){
  var collections = _.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
  async.forEach(collections, function (collectionName, next) {
    var collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName];
    collection.drop(function (err) {
      if (err && err.message != 'ns not found') return next(err);
      next(null);
    })
 }, function(err, result){
  done(err, result);
  });
}
```

I checked the database directly and the collection's unique index on the identifier is missing after the collection is deleted between runs.

Is there a way to rerun the Mongoose schemas so the indexes get recreated between each test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`ensureIndexes`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes) on each of your models, for instance in `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  var modelNames = _.keys(mongoose.models);
  async.forEach(modelNames, function (modelName, next) {
    mongoose.models[modelName].ensureIndexes(next);
  }, done);
});
```